# How to add dollar sign $ to strings in Dart?

Tags: dart, flutter

I need to use this `String` value. However, I cannot seem use the dollar sign "$".

```
Text('! @ # $ & * ~', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey))
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Dollar is a special character, you need to banalize them with a `\`

```
void main(){
    String s = "! @ # \$ & * ~";
    print('$s');
}
```

Answer (score 16):

Besides using a backslash in front of the dollar sign, you can also use a "raw string":

```
r'! @ # $ & * ~'
```

The "r" prefix indicates that dollar is no longer a special character.

Answer (score 9):

Just put `\$` and then works.

```
Text('\$800') = $800
```

Answer (score 4):

The reason this is not working for you is because the *dollar sign **`$`*** is used for *template literals*, which can be used to "[interpolate the value of Dart expressions within strings](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.3.1/dart-core/String-class.html)".
When only evaluating identifiers, just a dollar sign followed by the variable name is enough: `'foo: $foo'`
However, *curly braces* can be added to evaluate whole expressions: `'foo * bar: ${foo * bar}'`

Having said that, you will need to **escape** the dollar sign using a *backslash*: `'50\$'`

For your example: `Text('! @ # \$ & * ~', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey))`

Answer (score 4):

simply Write`Text("\$200",style:TextStyle(fontSize:))`

Answer (score 3):

The dollar is a special symbol and we use it for using variables inside the quotation marks.

```
String currency="ruppee"; 
Text('Indian currency is ${currency}');
```

so if we want to save the dollar symbol in string type we need to add `/` like this

```
String symbol = "\$";
```

Now we can use it as a string.

Answer (score 0):

check below code for $ sign

```
`String dollarSign = String.fromCharCodes(new Runes('\u0024'));
print(dollarSign):`
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an amount inside a variable and you want to display it with the dollar sign, do this.

```
void main() {
  double amount = 49.99;
  print('\$ ${amount}');
}
```

> Output: $ 49.99